How to Login using the Middleware 'auth'?
I'm having problems with the authentication because in the following methods when it entries to the authenticate method, I receive True in my validation Log::info("", ['authenticated' => Auth::check()]); but, when it redirects to "menu.index" i can't entry and i just go back to my window of login.
Here you have both codes:
Route::controller(menuController::class)->group(function() {
    Route::get('menu', 'index')->name('menu.index')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('menu/registro', 'register')->name('menu.register');
    Route::get('menu/registro', 'registro')->name('menu.registro');
    Route::get('menu/login', 'login')->name('menu.login');
    Route::post('menu/login', 'authenticate')->name('menu.authenticate');
    Route::post('menu/logout',  'logout')->name('menu.logout');
});

public function authenticate(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        // Log para saber si el método se está ejecutando
        Log::info('Entró a la función authenticate.');

        // Encuentra al usuario por su número de empleado
        $user = Login::where('numEmpleado', $request->numEmpleado)->first();

        // Verifica si el usuario existe y la contraseña es correcta
        if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            Log::info('Entró al if de autenticación.');

            // Inicia la sesión del usuario
            Auth::guard('web')->login($user);

            // Regenera la sesión para seguridad
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            Log::info("", ['authenticated' => Auth::check()]);
            //return view('auth.menu');
            //return request();
            return redirect()->intended(route('menu.index'));
        }

        Log::info('No se pudo autenticar al usuario, redirigiendo de vuelta.');
        return back()->withErrors(['error' => 'Credenciales incorrectas.'])->withInput($request->except('password'));
    }

Can you help me explaining me step by step? I´m a new student

Why did you tag this question both with laravel 4 and 5? Please only use the relevant tags

Please follow all the steps for debug the code:
Step 1: Verify Your Route and Middleware Configuration:
Route::get('menu', 'index')->name('menu.index')->middleware('auth');

Step 2: Check Authentication Logic:
Auth::guard('web')->login($user);
$request->session()->regenerate();

Step 3: Debugging Authentication:
Log::info("", ['authenticated' => Auth::check()]);

Step 4: Session and Cookie Configuration:
Check your config/session.php configuration

Step 5: Environment and Cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear

